# anyone ever used this email verification script?

Tags: email, smtp, email-verification

Trumail (https://github.com/trumail/trumail) is a free and open source email validation/verification system. but after installing it (we found an image in docker hub) we couldn't make it work and verify any email. if anyone has ever used it please send me a documentation or a video please .. thank you

https://github.com/trumail/trumail

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it. It's a good way to get your mailserver blacklisted.

It opens a connection to the remote server and starts a delivery attempt to the specified email address.

If you do this with more than a few bad addresses, many servers will blacklist you and if you're unluckily, will report it to one or more blacklist providers as a directory havest attack.

Comment: i can use it with one or two IP addresses .. that i wont use for emailing, buying an IP is cheaper than email verification services ... don't you think ?

Comment: As soon as the IP gets blacklisted (which won't take long) it will be useless.